# How do I use WMI to view Hidden (removed) devices

Tags: wmi

I know how to use WMI to get a list of current (plugged in) USB devices via:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
               new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
               "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
```

however, is there a way I can also see hidden devices (same as selecting "View->Show Hidden Devices" on Device Manager)?

Comment: I don't know `WMI` way but devices that are currently attached to the computer are listed by `DevCon Find *` operation. Then,  hidden devices could be supposedly those listed by [`DevCon FindAll *`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544761(v=vs.85).aspx) and concurrently **not** in `DevCon Find *` output.

Comment: Win32_PnPEntity definitely don't list hidden devices. Since I know there isn't a quick WMI way.

Comment: Did you find an answer to the question eventually?